# MongoDB aggregate returning an empty array

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregate, mongo-shell

So, my problem is, that in MongoDB that .aggregate() function is not working

**Heres some pictures:**

[image: mongo shell]
[image: friendRequests collection]
[image: users collection]

You can see what a tried on the first picture

Comment: If you use `from: "users",` in the `$lookup`, does it work?

Comment: No, its not working

Comment: Ahhh, `"friend_id"` is a string, not an ObjectId.  Should you change it?

Comment: how can i change it to an ObjectId?

Comment: You'll probably have the same issue with `"author"`.

Comment: And, can you tell me, how can i insert the data as an ObjectId in NestJS Typescript Mongoose?

Comment: I'm not a mongooser, but isn't the type/ref defined in the schema?

Comment: If i change it to ObjectId, the API crashes

Comment: It's probably best to search for a question similar to this issue, and then if you can't find one, ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, i will search for that issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`"$lookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), it's important that both `"localField"` values and `"foreignField"` values have the same type.

In this case, `"localField"` is a string and `"foreignField"` is an ObjectId.

It's probably best for queries to use ObjectId's for both.